# How can I set the username in slackapifileoperator?

Tags: slack-api

I'm trying to send a file to slack via airflow and using the `Slackapifileoperator`, however unlike the `slackapipostoperator`, there's no parameter to set the username. As a result, the file sent to slack is showing up under a colleague's username.
Is there any way to change that?

After setting up  DAG, this is my test code:

```
slack_operator_file=SlackAPIFileOperator(task_id="slack_file_test",
dag=dag,slack_conn_id="slack",
channels="#general,#random",
initial_comment="image test",filename="/files/test.png",filetype="png")
```